# How can I save custom post type details in wordpress 3.9.3 using 'save_post' hook?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I've created a custom post type 'promo-services' and added some custom meta_boxes, but i'm not able to save their values using 'add_action('save_post',);' it works only once when i click on add new custom post button but when I click on publish it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
<?php   
function saveServiceDetails(){
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
    }
    add_action('save_post', 'saveServiceDetails');</code>
?>
```

Comment: could you please put more code/info about this issue?

Comment: What Ethaan said. the code you did post is also missing a `</pre>`.... Mebbe best bet is to add wp_debug to your code to see if you are getting any php error messages.